# Check if a column contains a sequence

Tags: r, seq

I want to know, if i can check out if a column of a data frame starts with `0` or `1` and goes till the number of rows without breaking the sequence. Below is a sample data frame.

```
structure(list(X = 1:22, SNR = c(1.0035798429, 11.9438978154, 
NA, 3.2894877794, 4.0170266411, 1.6310522977, 1.6405414787, 1.6625412522, 
0.8489116253, 7.5312259672, 7.2832910726, 0.5732577083, NA, 0.8149754292, 
1.9981020389, 1.2477052103, 0.9960804911, 10.3402683931, 3.6328270728, 
2.5540496855, 41.96873985, 6.2035281045), ID = c(109L, 110L, 
111L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 116L, 117L, 118L, 119L, 120L, 121L, 123L, 
124L, 125L, 126L, 127L, 128L, 130L, 131L, 132L, 133L), SignalIntensity = c(6.8173738339, 
11.5459925418, NA, 9.7804203445, 9.8719842219, 9.0781857736, 
8.2289312163, 8.0435364446, 6.1793458315, 10.5581798932, 10.4745329822, 
4.1572943809, NA, 6.0451742752, 8.3100219509, 7.4558770659, 7.1464749962, 
11.4284386394, 9.6273795753, 9.6807417299, 13.3364944397, 10.4304671876
)), .Names = c("X", "SNR", "ID", "SignalIntensity"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-22L))
```

How can i check the columns and return the index if present.

Edited: The sequence i am looking for is a natural sequence. Suppose if a data frame has `10` rows, the column if present should have a sequence `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10` or may be like`0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9`. . So the sequence starts with `0` or `1` and goes till the number of rows with an increment of 1 for each row.

Comment: Clean question, messy sample data.

Comment: Without breaking what sequence? A leading zero or one does not make a sequence.

Comment: @MikeWise say it a sequence of natural numbers

Comment: @akrun this should have been your first comment :)

Comment: @akrun I think your solution is near, but i want the index of columns where the sequence is present

Comment: @akrun Please update your answer with `which` option also.

Comment: so we are just checking to see if they are all integers in a column? Or is this maybe supposed to be a monotonic sequence with constant difference between the points? What does "a sequence" mean to you?

Comment: @MikeWise say i have `10 rows` and the column if present should go like `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10` or may be `0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9` , which is a natural sequence

Comment: Suppose if the sequence is `0 2 4 6 8 10 12 14`

Comment: @akrun Not a true sequence

Comment: @akrun , The question is updated. Does your answer work for any other sequence.

Comment: My answer is specific to the case you mentioned.  But, I have another doubt. suppose you have NAs ie. `c(0:9, NA, 10)` would this be considered a sequence

Comment: @akrun False sequence

Comment: Updated the post, another case is `c(1:10, NA)` would this be a sequence?

Comment: @akrun The sequence should not break in any case. If its `c(1:10, NA), so it means there are `11` rows but sequence is from `1:10` only. So False

Comment: Okay, thanks, so my solution should work in all these cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could loop through the columns with `sapply`.  Create a function to check whether there are any NAs.  If not (`!any`), we get the difference (`diff`) between the adjacent element, check if all the element difference is 1 (`all(diff(x)==1`) and (`&`) the first value of the column is 0 or 1 (`x[1] %in% 0:1`).  If there is any NA, the output for that column will be 'FALSE'.

```
 f1 <- function(x) {
          if(!any(is.na(x)))
         all(diff(x)==1) & x[1] %in% 0:1
         else FALSE}
 which(sapply(df, f1))
 #X 
 #1
```

Comment: does this return an index?

Comment: @MikeWise I thought the OP wanted a logical index of columns.  I could be wrong.

Comment: If i have a list of data frames, how can i check for all

Comment: @AaghazHussain  If you have list , for e.g. `lst`. Try `lapply(lst, function(x) which(sapply(x, f1)))`